# What is the difference between make and mka?

Tags: android, makefile, build

So I'm building TWRP. I see that some use the command `make` when building the recovery image, e.g. `make -j5 recoveryimage`, but others use `mka recoveryimage`.

What is the difference between the two commands `make` and `mka`? I couldn't find a comprehensive answer on my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mka` is intended to be a faster `make`. Here's a nice description ([source](http://www.trcompu.com/MySmartPhone/AndroidKitchen/Breakfast-Brunch-Lunch.html)):

> This little gem of a command is basically equivalent to a super-charged version of make. Make is the program that gets called to build our source, choosing the correct compiler for each part of the Android OS that we are making. Problem is, make is SLOW in its default configuration. It can take hours longer depending on your hardware. So what did they do? They mated make with a cheetah, and took their child mka. mka improves upon make by using the program sched_tool to make full use of all the threads available on your machine (For AMD, this is equivalent to the number of cores your processor has; For Intel, this is usually equivalent to twice the number of cores your processor has, due to HyperThreading). What this means is that ALL of your processor is working, not just one small part of it.

Comment: Haha, that was a nice description. I understand now.

Comment: Is this true? Was this so far back that `make` didn't have parallel capabilities?

Comment: @Vroomfondel, `make` is slow *in its default configuration*. Looks like `mka` will just automatically calculate `-jN` value for `make`.

Comment: So I guess it's not different from typing `make -jN` manually?